# Renaming large tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to rename two large tables. The rename has been running for 24 hours and the `wait_type_event` on the rename has a `Lock` on it. Nothing is querying these tables right now. Is there a better way to rename large tables. I don't think this alter command will finish.

Comment: Do the two tables have a relationship between them? Does [pg_locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) show other queries holding a lock on the table from before the `RENAME`?

Comment: No reason to wait for 24 hours for something that should take less than a few milliseconds. Something is blocking your action, there is no relation with the size of your table. What does pg_stat_activity show you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming is very quick. The problem is a long running transaction that blocks you. Close, kill or otherwise terminate the blocking session and proceed.